# Automating download of SQL backups stored on Azure via powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to create a script that will download SQL backups from Azure before using docker to build containers.  I created a service principal using these instructions:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-2.4.0

I'm using the following code to try to start the downloads but it fails with the following error:

```
$tenantID = '6ed674z5-my tenant ID-802730b05737'
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'x43my long passwordR69' -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('079054cd-my application ID-0b19d8ar6e77', $passwd)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -TenantId $tenantId

$containerName = "mycontainer"
$location = "westus2"
$resourceGroup = "myresourcegroup"
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx |  Get-AzStorageblobcontent -Destination ".\dbase\backups" -Force
```

Error:

```
Get-AzStorageAccount : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At C:\dev\thcguard\launch.ps1:9 char:19
+ $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageAccount], ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountCommand
```

Where am I going wrong?  If I just use Connect-AzAccount and manually log in the download code works.

Comment: I looked at the storage blob and it says 
Authentication method: Access key (Switch to Azure AD User Account).  I have a hunch that one way to solve this might be switching to AD user account, but I need the access key method to do the SQL backups in the first place...

Comment: What's the output of $storageAccount?

Comment: I don't know how to dump the contents of a variable but since it's set using Get-AzStorageAccount it's likely just an error.  This code all works if I log in manually using just Connect-AzAccount

Comment: Add an extra line after your script that is just: $storageAccount

Comment: After the `Connect-AzAccount` line, Add this line `Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "my azure subscription id" -TenantId "my tenant id"`

Comment: Set-AzContext : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
At C:\dev\thcguard\launch.ps1:8 char:1
+ Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "56903a32-mysubscriptionid-81a93ffec5e8"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzContext], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.SetAzureRMContextCommand

Comment: How did you get your subscription id ?

Comment: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade

And adding the extra line didn't dump the storage account or it was one of the errors in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service principals don't have a default subscription.
While connecting using a user account, `Connect-AzAccount` fectches the default subscription. In your case, you need to specify the subscription you want to connect to.

You can adjust your code like that:

```
$tenantId = "{my-tenant-id}"
$subscriptionId = "{my-subscription-id}"
$applicationId = "{my-application-id}"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "{my-password}" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applicationId, $password)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCredential -TenantId $tenantId -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

Make sure your service principal can access your storage account. You can assign permission to the storage account, using the `Access control (IAM)` blade of the storage account:

[image]

Comment: Getting closer:  Connect-AzAccount : The provided account {accountID?} does not have access to subscription ID "{mysubscriptionID}". Please try logging in with different credentials or a
different subscription ID.

Comment: I got that accountID off the app registrations page

Comment: Oh ok so you need to grant permissions to your service principal to access the subscription or at least permissions on the blob storage it self.

Comment: I don't know what that means or how to do it :)  I'm just testing Azure so I don't know what I'm doing yet.

Comment: Thank you.  I've verified that the service principal has access as storage blob reader role.  I'm still getting Connect-AzAccount : The provided account {my applicationID} does not have access to subscription ID "{my subscriptionID}". Please try logging in with different credentials or a different subscription ID.  (https://www.screencast.com/t/2AEJO1Sd4X)

Comment: Also getting this error:  Get-AzStorageAccount : The client '{app object ID}' with object id '{app object ID}' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read'
over scope '/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}'  I don't see a storageAccountsRead role - only Storage Account Contributor which manages keys

Comment: There should be a data reader role. Can you grant reader role at the subscription level to your service principal